# What's the correct way to form the URI to the video file I intend to send to Whatsapp?

Tags: android, uri, whatsapp

I've been trying to send videos to Instagram and Whatsapp using the following code:

```
private void createShareIntent(String type, shareVectorList svList){

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File(pathName);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media); //This is the part I'm confused about

    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    switch(svList)
    {
        case INSTAGRAM:
            share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
            break;
        case WHATSAPP:
            share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

When I send the video to Instagram, it uploads fine. When I send the video to Whatsapp, however, it just shows a black screen where the video editing part is supposed to be.

When I look at the Android logs, it states a FileNotFoundException.

Someone told me it's because of the malformed URI, or the URI pointing to some file that doesn't exist.

I tried using `Uri.parse("file://" + pathName)`, but it still nets me the same Exception.

I tried getting the URI from the `ContentResolver`'s query with the following code:

```
public Uri retrieveUriFromVideoPath(String pathName) {
    File file = new File(pathName);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID },
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[] { pathName }, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID));
        cursor.close();
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (file.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, pathName);
            return getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

However it just returns me`content://media/external/images/media/<video_file_id>`, and the same Exception pops up.

My questions:

1. How should I form the URI that refers to the video I intend to share to Whatsapp?
2. If that video is in a custom folder I generate, would the same method work?
3. What if the file name contains whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what did the trick was using a FileProvider instead.

I added the following in the Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.thisFileProvider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/path_to_this_app_directory_permanent" />
</provider>
```

And for the URI I'll just have to do this: `Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.thisFileProvider", media);`

I frankly can't believe it took me this long to figure it out.